# Hosting single page with s3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I want to host my single page application on s3 with cloudfront. The only problem is that the index page has no versioning as it is a default root object. So does anyone know any good practise to have not cached index page with cloudfront?

Answer (score 2):

You can custom-configure a [default root object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html) in CloudFront, which specifies the actual file that CloudFront fetches from the origin when the request is for `/`.

Rolling out a new version of the root page is then done by changing the configured default root object in the distribution to point to the new index file.

Configuring this option does not change the way any other paths are interpreted, and does not cause a browser redirect to the specified target.  CloudFront just rewrites the path in the request before sending the request to the origin.

Comment: It does take a few minutes, yes.

Comment: This solved my issue. Surprisingly it was very difficult to find this answer, and I didn't find it until I found this issue prior to opening an issue myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching the same problem. I think the best solution I found was to upload the index.html file to S3 with a `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header. This should cause CloudFront to not cache the index file if `Minimum TTL = 0` ([Read more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationDownloadDist)). You can do this using the AWS S3 cli (`aws s3 cp`).

Another option is to invalidate using the invalidation API though it takes between 10-30 minutes to complete the invalidation.